# Loading data from multiple xls files to oracle table

Tags: oracle, xls, sql-loader

I have Multiple XLS files . I have stored these file names in a table as below

TABLE NAME    SEQUENCE

FILE1.XLS        1
FILE2.XLS        2
FILE3.XLS        3

Each file  has  3 fields

FIELD1  FIELD2 FILED3

Now I have to load to data in table  which has four column

FIELD1  FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4  ,  where FILED4 should be field by SEQUNCE of file  name.

Please suggest the way to load the data  from the files

Comment: what languages do you know?  there are countless ways depending on your skillset and current environment, not just "the" way

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the Excel spreadsheets to CSV you can load them using External tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTL_FILE package or external table. With external table you cannot use a wildcard while mentioning the file name, so you would need to run a loop and call it from a shell script.